# Use split environment multiple times in align

Tags: math-mode, align, labels, split

I got a big fan of the `split` environment to share forumula numberings over multiple lines.

However I can't figure out how to use it multiple times inside an align environment. I have an equation that needs to be split in multiple lines, some group of lines form one formula I want to label. How would one do that? the code below doesn't work...

A more precise working example of what I am trying to do:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
x^{(2)} &= \frac{1}{10} ( \varphi(x_1) +\varphi(-x_1) \\
& + \cdots \\
& + \varphi(100x_1) +\varphi(-100x_1) ) \\
\label{one}
\end{split}
\begin{split}
& + \frac{1}{10}\varphi_{tanh}( 100x_2)  +\frac{1}{10}\varphi_{tanh}(-100x_2)\\
& + \varphi_{tanh}(x_3)
\label{two}
\end{split}
\end{align} 

\end{document}
```

this produces the output, where I would expect the lines to be below each other:

[image]

Comment: Your code having two `\end{split}` but only one `\begin{split}` which caused compilation error, and can you explain your requirement with little more clear (sorry)...

Comment: Dang you're right, but that's not solving the issue. I will elaborate a bit more precisely in my question

Comment: you are missing a `\\ ` between the two split environments, but also please always post complete documents not fragments

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure whether to use `\\\` in the last column of a split environment or not but both variants produce the same output

Comment: no you have no `\\ ` in the align so nothing to make one come above the other (see Bernard's answer with aligned but split is the same)  note your example is still not a document that anyone can run to see the issue.

Comment: Thanks you´re I totally forgot to seperate the two split-parts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per David comment, `\\` required to separate both the lines and use `\quad` to align the operators. Off topic, in general, `trignometry` terms like `cos, sin` and `tan` should come in roman font only, so please use `\tanh` instead of `tanh` and the modified tags are:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
x^{(2)} &= \frac{1}{10} ( \varphi(100x_1+175) +\varphi(-100x_1+150) \\
&\quad + \cdots \\
&\quad + \varphi(100x_1-125) +\varphi(-100x_1-150) ) -\frac{1}{10}
\label{one}
\end{split}\\
\begin{split}
&\quad + \frac{1}{10}\varphi_{\tanh}( 100x_2+150)
+\frac{1}{10}\varphi_{\tanh}(-100x_2+150)\\
&\quad + \varphi_{\tanh}(x_5)
\label{two}
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you thats what I was looking for. The problem is I don't want to break style and I am also using `\varphi_{sig}` ad `\varphi_{smax}` etc. they should all have the same font. Is there a way to make `_{sig}` look like `_{\tanh}` ?

Comment: Glad to help you, you can define your own like `\DeclareMathOperator{\smax}{smax}` and the usage is `\varphi_{\smax}`...

Comment: thanks yeah you're right I didnt think of that

Answer (score 3):

I would do it with `aligned`, in this way:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath,mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\label{one}
 & \begin{aligned}x^{(2)} = & \mfrac{1}{10} ( \varphi(100x_1+175) +\varphi(-100x_1+150) + \cdots {}\\
& + \varphi(100x_1-125) +\varphi(-100x_1-150) ) -\smash{\mfrac{1}{10}}
\end{aligned}
\\[1ex]
  & \begin{aligned}
\phantom{x^{(2)} = }& + \mfrac{1}{10}\varphi_{\tanh}( 100x_2+150) +\mfrac{1}{10}\varphi_{\tanh}(-100x_2+150)\\
& + \varphi_{\tanh}(x_5)
\end{aligned}
\label{two}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks that works with split, as well. The hint to increase space between splits was helpful as well!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `aligned` in the following way, placing equation numbers at the top of each group and using extra indentation for visual grouping.  I also provide an alternative with just aligned, but then you have to remember to use `\notag` often.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Using \verb+aligned+
\begin{align}
  x^{(2)}
  &=
    \begin{aligned}[t]
      &\frac{1}{10} \bigl( \varphi(100x_1+175) +\varphi(-100x_1+150) \\
      &\qquad + \dotsb \\
      &\qquad + \varphi(100x_1-125) +\varphi(-100x_1-150) \bigr)
      -\frac{1}{10}
    \end{aligned}
        \label{one}
  \\
  &\hphantom{{}={}}
    \begin{aligned}[t]
      & + \frac{1}{10}\varphi_{\tanh}( 100x_2+150)
      +\frac{1}{10}\varphi_{\tanh}(-100x_2+150)\\
      &\qquad + \varphi_{\tanh}(x_5)
    \end{aligned}
        \label{two}
\end{align}

Or with just \verb+align+ and \verb+\notag+
\begin{align}
  x^{(2)}
  &=
    \frac{1}{10} \bigl( \varphi(100x_1+175) +\varphi(-100x_1+150) 
    \label{three}\\
  &\qquad + \dotsb \notag\\
  &\qquad + \varphi(100x_1-125) +\varphi(-100x_1-150) \bigr)
    -\frac{1}{10} \notag \\
  &\quad + \frac{1}{10}\varphi_{\tanh}( 100x_2+150)
    +\frac{1}{10}\varphi_{\tanh}(-100x_2+150) \label{four}\\
  &\qquad + \varphi_{\tanh}(x_5) \notag
\end{align}

\end{document}
```